# Is there a difference when using ～ものか/～もんか?

Tags: grammar, usage, colloquial-language, contractions

I was wondering if there's any difference in meaning when contracting this sentence-final.

For example:

> ボーナスもくれない会社でもう働く**ものか**。
>
> ボーナスもくれない会社でもう働く**もんか**。

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in meaning -- none.

The only difference is that 「も**ん**か」 is more informal and colloquial than 「も**の**か」.

Both are ***negative*** expressions as I hope you know.

"I'll no longer work for a company that doesn't give me bonuses!"